# Adjust screen brightness in Mac OS X app

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, brightness

I want to control the brightness of the main-screen within my Mac OS X app (like the F1/F2 buttons). In iOS, there's something like this:

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().brightness = CGFloat(0.5)
```

In OSX we have NSScreen, which is nice to find out what the main-screen is, but it misses the `.brightness` method.

So how can I adjust the monitor brightness using Swift on OSX?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's no such nice API for doing this on OS X.

We have to use `IOServiceGetMatchingServices` to find `"IODisplayConnect"` (the display device) then use the `kIODisplayBrightnessKey` to set the brightness:

```
func setBrightnessLevel(level: Float) {

    var iterator: io_iterator_t = 0

    if IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IODisplayConnect"), &iterator) == kIOReturnSuccess {

        var service: io_object_t = 1

        while service != 0 {

            service = IOIteratorNext(iterator)
            IODisplaySetFloatParameter(service, 0, kIODisplayBrightnessKey, level)
            IOObjectRelease(service)

        }

    }
}

setBrightnessLevel(0.5)
```

Comment: great solution, thank you! works perfectly fine on my MacBook with the build-in display. Could you please also give me a hint how to control the brightness of an external display, like a CinemaDisplay? Is it another IOService I have to match? I couldn't find any help in the Apple Docs.

Comment: Since we're interating the services matching "IODisplayConnect" I think it will work for internal and external displays (it should apply on all displays it finds, actually). If it doesn't work for you then I'll inspect further. *Note that some external displays can not be setup programmatically from OS X anyway.*

Comment: I tested it with an actual MacBookPro (with the latest OSX 10.11 Beta) and an Apple Thunderbold Display connected via DisplayPort/Thunderbold. The build-in display reacts, but the Thunderbold-Display didn't. `NSScreen.screens()` returns two displays correctly. I appreciate your support :)

Comment: Do you have any idea yet why it's not working with multiple displays?

Comment: No, I've tested lots of stuff but haven't found why we don't get external displays with this method, and haven't found relevant documentation about it either. All other methods I've found are now deprecated and don't work at all. I only see this incomplete one for now in 10.10+.

Comment: following command lists the display as AppleDisplay. Not sure if that in internal or external. ioreg -l | grep -5 IODisplayEDID

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you! As an addition to this answer, if you need to control external displays, you can do this through IOKit as well, using DDC. Another fine gentleman wrote an application for this called `ddcctl` which you can find on github. I am currently working on adding an option to this app that would allow it to track the main display and set the external to match brightness.

Comment: works perfectly but I think that due to macOS restrictions or a bug, the brightness slider in the setting does not change when you set a new brightness.