# How to adjust screen brightness in macOS app?

Tags: macos, swiftui, apple-silicon

I'm looking for a way to adjust the screen brightness programmatically in my macOS SwiftUI app. Currently i have this function from [@ericaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227743/eric-aya) in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691397/adjust-screen-brightness-in-mac-os-x-app)

```
func setBrightnessLevel(level: Float) {

    var iterator: io_iterator_t = 0

    if IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IODisplayConnect"), &iterator) == kIOReturnSuccess {

        var service: io_object_t = 1

        while service != 0 {

            service = IOIteratorNext(iterator)
            IODisplaySetFloatParameter(service, 0, kIODisplayBrightnessKey, level)
            IOObjectRelease(service)

        }

    }
}

setBrightnessLevel(0.5)
```

However that doesn't work on the Apple silicon Macs (M1, M2 etc.) due to limitations in using IOKit for Apple silicon.

So I'm wondering if anyone has a solution for this that works for both Intel based Macs and Apple silicon (ARM architecture) Macs?